# Overwriting multiple previous terminal outputs

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack-dev-server, readline

I have a webpack-dev-server proxy, and I want to display the requests to the proxy in the terminal window while the server is running. What complicates this is that I want to display the request when it is received, then update what was originally written once the response is received back with the status code.  For instance, if I were to request GET /foo, I want this initially displayed:

```
(---) GET /foo
```

Then, if the proxy returns a 200 response status I want that console output to be updated like this:

```
(200) GET /foo
```

I have this (mostly) working with this:

```
const readline = require('readline');
// ...
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        onProxyReq: function (proxyReq, req, res) {
            process.stdout.write(`(---) ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
            proxyReq.on('response', function(response) {
                readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 0);
                readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, null);
                process.stdout.write(`(${response.statusCode}) ${req.method} ${req.url}\n`);
            });
        }
    }
}
// ...
```

Where it fails is when multiple requests are received before any responses are returned, in which case the output looks similar to the following:

```
(---) GET /foo/1(---) GET /bar/2(---) GET /baz/3
(200) GET /bar/2
(200) GET /baz/3
(200) GET /foo/1
```

I have looked at using [readline's](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/readline.html) `moveCursor` versus `cursorTo`, but I don't know how to track which line number was previously written.

How can I modify what I have currently to keep track and overwrite the correct console output line when the response is received?

Comment: Have you tried calling `readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 0)` just before the line `process.stdout.write(\`(---) ${req.method} ${req.url}\`);`

Comment: @DougCoburn I didn't expect it to work, but some quick testing after adding both the `clearLine` followed by `cursorTo` seems to work good enough for the moment. The requests I'm testing with may not be lasting long enough for me to see, but I think this way would only leave a single 'outstanding' log statement that needs to be overwritten at a time. If I had 5 long-running requests then I don't think it would work as I intend, unless I'm just totally missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use a `readline.moveCursor` to move the cursor relative to its current position to go back to the line corresponding to the request.  This also means that you need to keep track of your current line or always move it back to `x: 0` after each write.

The following snippet isn't quite what you are looking for, but it demonstrates how to use the readline cursor commands to overwrite your existing console output over time.

```js
const readline = require('readline')

let i = 0;
const next = () => {
    if (i && i%3 === 0) readline.moveCursor(process.stdout, null, -3)
    readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, null);
    readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 0);
    process.stdout.write(`${i}\n`);
    i += 1;
    if (i < 9) setTimeout(next, 200);
    else console.log();
}
setTimeout(next, 200);
```

For your specific example, I think you want something more akin to the following:

```js
const readline = require('readline');
// ...
urls = [];
const rowOf = url => {
    let row = urls.indexOf(req.url);
    if (row === -1) {
        row = urls.length;
        urls.push(req.url);
    }
    return row;
}

const writeLine = (row, str) => {
    readline.moveCursor(process.stdout, null, row);
    readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, null);
    readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 0);
    process.stdout.write(str);
    readline.moveCursor(process.stdout, null, -1*row);
    readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, null);
}

devServer: {
    proxy: {
        onProxyReq: function (proxyReq, req, res) {
            writeLine(rowOf(req.url), `(---) ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
            proxyReq.on('response', function(response) {
                writeLine(rowOf(req.url), `(${response.statusCode}) ${req.method} ${req.url}\n`)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, it doesn't seem quite right and I can add some sort of limit to the size of the `urls` array, but at least points me in a good direction. Thanks Doug.